# casperjsをjenkins上で実行

Tags: casperjs, jenkins

casperjsをjenkins上で実行しようとするとpermission deniedとなってしまいます
基本的な質問ですみませんが、ジョブの指定方法やシェルの記述について教えていただけますでしょうか。
centos(vagrant)上で起動しています。

以下のジョブを登録(外部シェルを実行)

```
export WORKSPACE
sh -x ${WORKSPACE}/sample.sh
```

sample.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/vagrant/casperjs/bin/casperjs --version
```

結果

```
ユーザーanonymousが実行
ビルドします。 ワークスペース: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/casperjs
[casperjs] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3290936055601663011.sh
+ export WORKSPACE
+ sh -x /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/casperjs/sample.sh
+ /home/vagrant/casperjs/bin/casperjs --version
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/casperjs/sample.sh: line 2: /home/vagrant/casperjs/bin/casperjs: 許可がありません
Build step 'シェルの実行' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Jenkinsの実行ユーザーが `/home/vagrant/casperjs/bin/casperjs` を実行できる権限を持っていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dmnlkさんが既にコメントされていますが、sample.sh内でcasperjsを実行する所でpermission deniedとなっているので、ジョブの指定方法やシェルの書き方に問題があるというより、casperjsのアクセス権限の問題と思われます。

手元の環境ではcasperjsの実行権限を**rwxr--r--**（744）にすると同様のエラーが出ました。
一方、casperjsの実行権限を**rwxr-xr-x**（755）にすると正常に実行出来ました。

Jenkinsのジョブはデフォルトだとjenkinsというユーザで実行されているようなので、jenkinsにcasperjsの実行権限があるかを確認すると良いと思います。なお、Jenkinsのジョブの実行ユーザは以下のようにwhoamiコマンドを叩いて確認できます。

```
export WORKSPACE
sh -x ${WORKSPACE}/sample.sh
whoami
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。実行権限を付けたところ実行できました!

Comment: @kikucci 解決出来て良かったです。本質問が解決済みであることを他のユーザーに分かりやすくするため、回答にチェックマークを付けて頂ければと思われます。